# Docker: edit docker-entrypoint.sh based on environment variable

Tags: docker

I built a Docker image with an entrypoint.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
[...]
./app/dehydrated/dehydrated -c -t dns-01 -k '/app/dehydrated/hook.sh' -x
```

And this is the final part of Dockerfile

```
[...]
ENTRYPOINT [ "docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

I launch the container with

`docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/data:/app/dehydrated --name cfhookbash sineverba/cfhookbash:latest`

I want to add an env var:

`--env FORCE_RENEW=true`

So to edit on the fly my entrypoint as follow (pseudocode)

```sh
if $FORCE_RENEW && FORCE_RENEW == TRUE then
./app/dehydrated/dehydrated -c -t dns-01 -k '/app/dehydrated/hook.sh' -x
else
./app/dehydrated/dehydrated -c -t dns-01 -k '/app/dehydrated/hook.sh'
```

(So add the parameter X or no based on the env).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you can do in normal shell script syntax is legal in an entrypoint shell script.  I might write this as:

```sh
RENEW_OPT=
if [ "$FORCE_RENEW" == TRUE ]; then
  RENEW_OPT=-x
fi
./app/dehydrated/dehydrated -c -t dns-01 -k '/app/dehydrated/hook.sh' $RENEW_OPT
```

If you control the `dehydrated` application, setting it to directly understand the `$FORCE_RENEW` environment variable will be easier to set up than this command-line option.  The mechanism for that will be language-specific, but `docker run -e` sets a perfectly ordinary environment variable.

A further option is to embrace the ["container as command" pattern](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint).  Anything you pass as the "command" part of the container invocation -- anything after the image name in the `docker run` command -- gets passed as arguments to the entrypoint script, and you can use that to pass arbitrary options to your main program.

```sh
# entrypoint.sh
# -- does not specifically check for environment variables
# -- "$@" expands to any additional arguments
./app/dehydrated/dehydrated -c -t dns-01 -k '/app/dehydrated/hook.sh' "$@"
```

```sh
# Pass additional options after image name
docker run -it --rm 
  sineverba/cfhookbash:latest \
  -x
```

Comment: Thank you. I use your first option ;)